# Can someone please explain how freeletics works?

Tags: personal-training

I have been planning to follow some personal training program. I just came to know about [Freeletics](https://www.freeletics.com/en). Can someone who has already using freeletics, explain what freeletics is, how does it work? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "how does it work"? It's just bodyweight training, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but I wonder how effective a bot to motivate me for training. How it helps me to transformation.

Comment: Your motivation to do as the app says is completely up to you. If you have no discipline, then no app will be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

So I have looked at freeletics and started using it but I didn't want to pay and the app functionality is limited without getting through a paywall. The app itself is designed to basically give you a full personal training telling you what to do everyday of the week along with videos of the form you should be using. Personally I think the idea in and of itself is great. For some pretty small fee you basically get a personal trainers worth of advice and planning without the 100$ a session for a plan. That being said I am still a cheapskate and I don't like paying for things so I would recommend Nike Training club.

Transformation and motivation not guaranteed but the app covers two basic things as far as I can see: getting a plan and showing the right form. Given that you have those two things covered the rest is up to you. Freeletics also has a dietary one which I don't know how well it works.

**Disclaimer:** I have no personal interest in any of these platforms just my experience